# How to use select option value (string) inside a d3.Threshold.range() that needs an object in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, string, object, d3.js

Using d3.js I get the value of a select box and pass it to the .range() of a .scaleThreshold().

This is the select box:

```
<select id="color_scheme">
  <option value="d3.schemeOranges[7]">Orange</option>
<select>
```

This is how I get the value of the select box:

`var color_scheme = d3.select("#color_scheme").property("value");`

And this is the colorScale:

```
    const colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
        .domain([10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000])
        .range(color_scheme);
```

The problem is that in this case `color_scheme` is a string and it won't work inside the .range() brackets.

If you console.log it you just receive the string `d3.schemeOranges[7]` back.

But when you hardcode `var color_scheme` directly to `color_scheme = d3.schemeOranges[7]` it works.

And if you console.log it you receive the right object as expected:

```
[
    "#fff5eb",
    "#fee6ce",
    "#fdd0a2",
    "#fdae6b",
    "#fd8d3c",
    "#f16913",
    "#d94801",
    "#a63603",
    "#7f2704"
]
```

So the question is: how we can get the select value to work properly inside the .range()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following. Change your input to:

```
<select id="color_scheme">
  <option value="schemeOranges">Orange</option>
<select>
```

Then in your js, using the string, the array is:

```
d3[color_scheme][7]
```

Comment: @SmokeySharkers it work when I put value="schemeOranges". I'm not alowed to edit the answer. But with this modification, it worked. Thanks!